# Depending on Dependencies

Tags: object-oriented-design, dependency-injection

```
public class Connection : IConnection
{
    public Connection(Uri baseAddress, ISerializer serializer)
    {
        BaseAddress = baseAddress;

        Serializer = serializer;

        ResponseFactory = new ResponseFactory(serializer);
    }

    private Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }

    public IResponseFactory ResponseFactory { get; set; }

    private ISerializer Serializer { get; }
}
```

In this code (redacted for brevity), the `Connection` class has two dependencies that it gets via constructor injection.

It has a third dependency, on `IResponseFactory`, where property injection is available but a default is created via the line `ResponseFactory = new ResponseFactory(serializer)` in the constructor. I suppose the view was that `ResponseFactory` is a suitable 'local default', to use Mark Seemann's terminology, but a user of the `Connection` class is free to provide an alternative `IResponseFactory` should they wish.

On revisiting this code after some time, I'm ambivalent about the the creation of the local default in the constructor and its dependency on `ISerializer`. While `ISerializer` is required in its on right by the `Connection` class, 'chaining' it together with `ResponseFactory` seems wrong. It feels like the `Connection` class should require an `IResponseFactory` via the constructor and forego the convenience of the local default and its dependency on `ISerializer`, that just happens to also be injected into this class.

What do you think? Is this a defined 'smell'?

Comment: It seems odd to me. I would prefer overloading the constructor (or optional parameter with default value), and make the response factory `{ get; private set; }` set only in a constructor, unless we really know that we want this aspect of the object to be (dynamically) mutable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does look a bit odd for a number of reasons.

1. Mix of property and constructor injection
2. Is ISerializer a real requirement if its only used in ResponseFactory?
3. Always create a ResponseFactory even if its never used?
4. What happens if I switch the ResponseFactory around mid lifecycle of Connection?

Standard 'Code Smell' disclaimers

- a 'code smell' only indicates a possible problem, it doesn't mean there is definitely a problem.
- we cant see the whole code, maybe this way is needed for some reason

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `ISerializer` is a real requirement, it's used elsewhere but the code sample has been stripped down to aid focus. Likewise, `ResponseFactory` is used elsewhere but not shown. Regarding switching `IResponseFactory`, this is due to the simplistic implementation of that dependency's property injection. That's a different problem! Why do you consider the mixing of property and constructor injection to be a problem?

Comment: That addresses most of the code smells. Yes, Ideally I would have everything one way or the other. Preferably constructor as it enforces the dependency. You havent marked the property as 'required to be set' in any way, so I would not think to use it as an injection point

Answer (score 0):

The question is, whether the `ResponseFactory` is *necessary* to do anything meaningful or not.

**YES?** Then it should be provided via constructor injection. On the one side, it is nice, that the constructor provides a somehow *sensible default*. But on the other side, the constructor injection makes things *explicit*.

**NO?** Then there is no need for a `locale default`. A simply uninitialized field would be sufficient - at the cost of a null check. When it isn't needed, and in case it is, but it was overlooked there should be a clear signal (other than a NPE) that the caller hasn't done his homework.

---

Regarding @Ewan's answer:

> Mix of property and constructor injection

I see no problem in providing *necessary* dependencies via constructor injection, while *optional* ones via setter injection.